# About search path of cocos2dx in android project

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am recently developing a game with cocos2d-x.
I am first developing it for iOS project. It works well.

But then I tried to convert it to an android project.
I used build_native.sh to build the project, but I got an error message like this:

> jni/../../Classes/cocos2d-extension/native/CCNative.h:5:33: fatal error: cocos2dx_extensions.h: No such file or directory

It apparently says that it cannot find some library when building the project.

So, I am wondering if I need to make some configuration to let my project build correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Be sured to define all the environment variables required. Then you can use sample example android versions under samples to make things simpler and to verify your environment is ready. Then you may try again.